# Doubt on Pauli matrices eigenvectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, eigenvalue

I want to write the $\sigma_{z}$ eigenvectors $\{|+\rangle,|-\rangle\}$, in terms of the eigenvectors of $\sigma_{x}$, $\{|+\rangle _{x},|-\rangle _{x}\}$. But I simply didn't reach the right result:

$|+\rangle = a |+\rangle_{x} + b|-\rangle_{x} \implies |+\rangle =a\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\-1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} \implies a = b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \implies$

> $$|+\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix} $$

Similar problem occurs to the other eigenket. So, how can I write the basis  $\{|+\rangle,|-\rangle\}$, in terms of the eigenvectors of $\sigma_{x}$, $\{|+\rangle _{x},|-\rangle _{x}\}$?

Comment: I do not see what is wrong with your answer here.

Comment: @Mauricio shouldn't be: $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( |+\rangle_{x} + |-\rangle_{x}\big) $ ?

Comment: If $(1,\pm 1)/\sqrt{2}= |\pm\rangle_x$, then that's what you got.

Comment: $a=b=\sqrt{2}/2 = 1/\sqrt{2}$.